# How does one prove this bijection of hom-sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $X,Y$ and $Z$ are sets, how do you prove the bijection $$\text{Hom}(Y\times X,Z)\cong \text{Hom}(Y,\text{Hom}(X,Z))\;\;\;\;?$$ 
This is a specification of an "adjunction" in Category theory. I wonder if it has any applications in the form stated above.

Comment: Related: [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Comment: Isn't this the same question with [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707986/exponentials-in-mathbfset)?

Answer (score 3):

- Any map $\psi\colon Y\times X\to Z$ gives you a map
  \begin{align}
  \tilde \psi\colon Y &\longrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(X,Z), \\
  y &\longmapsto \psi(y,\,\cdot\,).
  \end{align}
- Any map $\tilde\varphi\colon Y \to \operatorname{Hom}(X,Z)$ gives you a map
  \begin{align}
  \varphi\colon X\times Y &\longrightarrow Z, \\
  (x,y) &\longmapsto \big((\tilde\varphi)(y)\big)(x).
  \end{align}

Can you show that these constructions are mutually inverse?

Comment: Yes, I can; Thank you very much.